# How to load video using python

Tags: python, video

I have a video saved in `.avi` format i wanted to see the video to see the video using python.
By seeing i wanted to :-

1. watch the video
2. get every frame(array) of the video.

Comment: untagging specific libraries because you haven't even tried to use them.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  i have used opencv and pil to load an image. but i have never used them to record and load a video. i found a method to record a vid but i didnt found a method to read a vid. Didnt tagged any uspecific library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')
success,frame = vidcap.read()
```

Comment: thanks this works for me. I though Videocapture is only used for reading videostream from camera.

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken you can use pygame or open cv2 for displaying images, do you need the sound too?

Comment: No i dont need sound since i am using this video frames for action detection. So my tensorflow model dosent need any sound.

Comment: ah its for tensorflow, look at this post: https://learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/